# Split column with JSON string to columns each containing one key-value pair from the string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have a data frame that looks like this (one column named "value" with a JSON string in it). I send it to an Event Hub using Kafka API and then I want to read that data from the Event Hub and apply some transformations to it. The data is in received in binary format, as described in the Kafka documentation.

[image]

Here are a few columns in CSV format:

```
value
"{""id"":""e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8"",""latitude"":""34.5016064725731"",""longitude"":""123.43996453687777""}"
"{""id"":""32782100-9b59-49c7-9d56-bb4dfc368a86"",""latitude"":""49.938541626415144"",""longitude"":""111.88360885971986""}"
"{""id"":""a72a600f-2b99-4c41-a388-9a24c00545c0"",""latitude"":""4.988768300413497"",""longitude"":""-141.92727675177588""}"
"{""id"":""5a5f056a-cdfd-4957-8e84-4d5271253509"",""latitude"":""41.802942545247134"",""longitude"":""90.45164573613573""}"
"{""id"":""d00d0926-46eb-45dd-9e35-ab765804340d"",""latitude"":""70.60161063520081"",""longitude"":""20.566520665122482""}"
"{""id"":""dda14397-6922-4bb6-9be3-a1546f08169d"",""latitude"":""68.400462882435"",""longitude"":""135.7167027587489""}"
"{""id"":""c7f13b8a-3468-4bc6-9db4-e0b1b34bf9ea"",""latitude"":""26.04757722355835"",""longitude"":""175.20227554031783""}"
"{""id"":""97f8f1cf-3aa0-49bb-b3d5-05b736e0c883"",""latitude"":""35.52624182094499"",""longitude"":""-164.18066699972852""}"
"{""id"":""6bed49bc-ee93-4ed9-893f-4f51c7b7f703"",""latitude"":""-24.319581484353847"",""longitude"":""85.27338980948076""}"
```

What I want to do is to apply a transformation and create a data frame with 3 columns one with id, one with latitude and one with longitude.
This is what I tried but the result is not what I expected:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# df is the data frame received from Kafka
location_schema = StructType().add("id", "string").add("latitude", "float").add("longitude", "float")
string_df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").withColumn("value", from_json(F.col("value"), location_schema))
string_df.printSchema()
string_df.show()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

It created a "value" column with a structure as a value. Any idea what to do to obtain 3 different columns, as I described?

Comment: Please include few rows of `df` dataframe as text/code instead of image

Answer (score 1):

Your df:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
(1, '{"id":"e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8","latitude":"34.5016064725731","longitude":"123.43996453687777"}'),
(2, '{"id":"32782100-9b59-49c7-9d56-bb4dfc368a86","latitude":"49.938541626415144","longitude":"111.88360885971986"}'),
(3, '{"id":"a72a600f-2b99-4c41-a388-9a24c00545c0","latitude":"4.988768300413497","longitude":"-141.92727675177588"}'),
(4, '{"id":"5a5f056a-cdfd-4957-8e84-4d5271253509","latitude":"41.802942545247134","longitude":"90.45164573613573"}'),
(5, '{"id":"d00d0926-46eb-45dd-9e35-ab765804340d","latitude":"70.60161063520081","longitude":"20.566520665122482"}'),
(6, '{"id":"dda14397-6922-4bb6-9be3-a1546f08169d","latitude":"68.400462882435","longitude":"135.7167027587489"}'),
(7, '{"id":"c7f13b8a-3468-4bc6-9db4-e0b1b34bf9ea","latitude":"26.04757722355835","longitude":"175.20227554031783"}'),
(8, '{"id":"97f8f1cf-3aa0-49bb-b3d5-05b736e0c883","latitude":"35.52624182094499","longitude":"-164.18066699972852"}'),
(9, '{"id":"6bed49bc-ee93-4ed9-893f-4f51c7b7f703","latitude":"-24.319581484353847","longitude":"85.27338980948076"}')
    ],
    ['id', 'value']
).drop('id')

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id":"e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8","latitude":"34.5016064725731","longitude":"123.43996453687777"}  |
|{"id":"32782100-9b59-49c7-9d56-bb4dfc368a86","latitude":"49.938541626415144","longitude":"111.88360885971986"}|
|{"id":"a72a600f-2b99-4c41-a388-9a24c00545c0","latitude":"4.988768300413497","longitude":"-141.92727675177588"}|
|{"id":"5a5f056a-cdfd-4957-8e84-4d5271253509","latitude":"41.802942545247134","longitude":"90.45164573613573"} |
|{"id":"d00d0926-46eb-45dd-9e35-ab765804340d","latitude":"70.60161063520081","longitude":"20.566520665122482"} |
|{"id":"dda14397-6922-4bb6-9be3-a1546f08169d","latitude":"68.400462882435","longitude":"135.7167027587489"}    |
|{"id":"c7f13b8a-3468-4bc6-9db4-e0b1b34bf9ea","latitude":"26.04757722355835","longitude":"175.20227554031783"} |
|{"id":"97f8f1cf-3aa0-49bb-b3d5-05b736e0c883","latitude":"35.52624182094499","longitude":"-164.18066699972852"}|
|{"id":"6bed49bc-ee93-4ed9-893f-4f51c7b7f703","latitude":"-24.319581484353847","longitude":"85.27338980948076"}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

json_schema = StructType([
                          StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                          StructField("latitude", FloatType(), True),
                          StructField("longitude", FloatType(), True)
                         ])

df\
    .withColumn('json', F.from_json(F.col('value'), json_schema))\
    .select(F.col('json').getItem('id').alias('id'),
            F.col('json').getItem('latitude').alias('latitude'),
            F.col('json').getItem('longitude').alias('longitude')
           )\
    .show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|id                                  |latitude           |longitude          |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8|34.5016064725731   |123.43996453687777 |
|32782100-9b59-49c7-9d56-bb4dfc368a86|49.938541626415144 |111.88360885971986 |
|a72a600f-2b99-4c41-a388-9a24c00545c0|4.988768300413497  |-141.92727675177588|
|5a5f056a-cdfd-4957-8e84-4d5271253509|41.802942545247134 |90.45164573613573  |
|d00d0926-46eb-45dd-9e35-ab765804340d|70.60161063520081  |20.566520665122482 |
|dda14397-6922-4bb6-9be3-a1546f08169d|68.400462882435    |135.7167027587489  |
|c7f13b8a-3468-4bc6-9db4-e0b1b34bf9ea|26.04757722355835  |175.20227554031783 |
|97f8f1cf-3aa0-49bb-b3d5-05b736e0c883|35.52624182094499  |-164.18066699972852|
|6bed49bc-ee93-4ed9-893f-4f51c7b7f703|-24.319581484353847|85.27338980948076  |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If pattern remains unchanged then you can use regexp_replace()

```
>>> df = spark.read.option("header",False).option("inferSchema",True).csv("/dir1/dir2/Sample2.csv")
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|_c0                                              |_c1                                 |_c2                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|"{""id"":""e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8""|""latitude"":""34.5016064725731""   |""longitude"":""123.43996453687777""}" |
|"{""id"":""32782100-9b59-49c7-9d56-bb4dfc368a86""|""latitude"":""49.938541626415144"" |""longitude"":""111.88360885971986""}" |
|"{""id"":""a72a600f-2b99-4c41-a388-9a24c00545c0""|""latitude"":""4.988768300413497""  |""longitude"":""-141.92727675177588""}"|
|"{""id"":""5a5f056a-cdfd-4957-8e84-4d5271253509""|""latitude"":""41.802942545247134"" |""longitude"":""90.45164573613573""}"  |
|"{""id"":""d00d0926-46eb-45dd-9e35-ab765804340d""|""latitude"":""70.60161063520081""  |""longitude"":""20.566520665122482""}" |
|"{""id"":""dda14397-6922-4bb6-9be3-a1546f08169d""|""latitude"":""68.400462882435""    |""longitude"":""135.7167027587489""}"  |
|"{""id"":""c7f13b8a-3468-4bc6-9db4-e0b1b34bf9ea""|""latitude"":""26.04757722355835""  |""longitude"":""175.20227554031783""}" |
|"{""id"":""97f8f1cf-3aa0-49bb-b3d5-05b736e0c883""|""latitude"":""35.52624182094499""  |""longitude"":""-164.18066699972852""}"|
|"{""id"":""6bed49bc-ee93-4ed9-893f-4f51c7b7f703""|""latitude"":""-24.319581484353847""|""longitude"":""85.27338980948076""}"  |
+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+

>>> df.withColumn("id",regexp_replace('_c0','\"\{\"\"id\"\":\"\"','')).withColumn("id",regexp_replace('id','\"\"','')).withColumn("latitude",regexp_replace('_c1','\"\"latitude\"\":\"\"','')).withColumn("latitude",regexp_replace('latitude','\"\"','')).withColumn("longitude",regexp_replace('_c2','\"\"longitude\"\":\"\"','')).withColumn("longitude",regexp_replace('longitude','\"\"\}\"','')).drop("_c0").drop("_c1").drop("_c2").show()
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                  id|           latitude|          longitude|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|e52f247c-f46c-402...|   34.5016064725731| 123.43996453687777|
|32782100-9b59-49c...| 49.938541626415144| 111.88360885971986|
|a72a600f-2b99-4c4...|  4.988768300413497|-141.92727675177588|
|5a5f056a-cdfd-495...| 41.802942545247134|  90.45164573613573|
|d00d0926-46eb-45d...|  70.60161063520081| 20.566520665122482|
|dda14397-6922-4bb...|    68.400462882435|  135.7167027587489|
|c7f13b8a-3468-4bc...|  26.04757722355835| 175.20227554031783|
|97f8f1cf-3aa0-49b...|  35.52624182094499|-164.18066699972852|
|6bed49bc-ee93-4ed...|-24.319581484353847|  85.27338980948076|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the sample data provided, created a dataframe called `df` and proceeded to use the same method as you.

- The following is the image of the rows present inside `df` dataframe.

[image]

- The fields are not displayed as required because of the their datatype. The values for `latitude` and `longitude` are present as `string` types in the dataframe `df`. But while creating the schema `location_schema` you have specified their type as `float`. Instead, try changing their type to `string` and later convert them to `double type`. The code looks as shown below:

```
location_schema = StructType().add("id", "string").add("latitude", "string").add("longitude", "string")
string_df = df.selectExpr('CAST(value AS STRING)').withColumn("value", from_json(F.col("value"), location_schema))
string_df.printSchema()
string_df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

- Now using `DataFrame.withColumn(), Column.withField() and cast()` convert the string type fields latitude and longitude to `Double Type`.

```
string_df = string_df.withColumn("value", col("value").withField("latitude", col("value.latitude").cast(DoubleType())))\
            .withColumn("value", col("value").withField("longitude", col("value.longitude").cast(DoubleType())))

string_df.printSchema()
string_df.show(truncate=False)
```

- So, you can get the desired output as shown below.

[image]

**Update:**

- To get separate columns you can simply use `json_tuple()` method. Refer to this official spark documentation:

[pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple — PySpark 3.3.0 documentation (apache.org)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_tuple`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple.html#pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple) to extract values from JSON string.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('{"id":"e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8","latitude":"34.5016064725731","longitude":"123.43996453687777"}',)],
    ['value'])
```

Script:

```py
cols = ['id', 'latitude', 'longitude']
df = df.select(F.json_tuple('value', *cols)).toDF(*cols)
```

```py
df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
# |id                                  |latitude        |longitude         |
# +------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
# |e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8|34.5016064725731|123.43996453687777|
# +------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

*If needed, `cast` to double:*

```py
.withColumn('latitude', F.col('latitude').cast('double'))
.withColumn('longitude', F.col('longitude').cast('double'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to extract JSON string as columns using [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) and [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json)

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('{"id":"e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8","latitude":"34.5016064725731","longitude":"123.43996453687777"}',)],
    ['value'])

df = df.selectExpr(
    "inline(array(from_json(value, 'struct<id:string, latitude:string, longitude:string>')))"
)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
# |id                                  |latitude        |longitude         |
# +------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
# |e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8|34.5016064725731|123.43996453687777|
# +------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```